# HP Procurve 2910 Inter VLAN routing partially working

Tags: routing, vlan, hp-procurve

I'm in the middle of slowly trying to solve my inherited ip range issue.

Currently everything is on 100.100.100.x. I am slowly moving things over to a 10.12.x.x range. Currently my Watchguard firewall on 100.100.100.222 is doing my for users, I want to change so the Procurve on 100.100.100.79 does the routing instead.

The first stage has been to set up a second connection to the firewall on VLAN 99 10.12.99.1 so internet access works and I've got it working on VLAN 123.

Here is my vlan setup.

```
VLAN ID Name                 | Status     Voice Jumbo
------- -------------------- + ---------- ----- -----
1       DEFAULT_VLAN         | Port-based No    No
20      ISCSI                | Port-based No    No
99      DMZ                  | Port-based No    No
121     Client_PCs           | Port-based No    No
122     Production           | Port-based No    No
123     Servers              | Port-based No    No
```

I can ping between VLAN 1 and 123. 
I can't ping between VLAN 122 and 123.

Here is my running config
    ; J9145A Configuration Editor; Created on release #W.14.38

```
hostname "AKS-BROX-SW2"
module 1 type J9145A
interface 24
   name "LINK TO FP"
exit
trunk 19-22 Trk1 LACP
trunk 6-9 Trk2 LACP
ip default-gateway 100.100.100.222
ip routing
vlan 1
   name "DEFAULT_VLAN"
   untagged 1-3,5,10,24,Trk1-Trk2
   ip address 100.100.100.79 255.255.255.0
   no untagged 4,11-18,23
   exit
vlan 20
   name "ISCSI"
   untagged 11-18
   ip address 172.16.230.253 255.255.255.0
   tagged Trk1
   exit
vlan 121
   name "Client_PCs"
   ip address 10.12.1.254 255.255.255.0
   tagged Trk2
   exit
vlan 122
   name "Production"
   ip address 10.12.2.254 255.255.255.0
   tagged 1-2,5,10-11,Trk2
   exit
vlan 123
   name "Servers"
   ip address 10.12.3.254 255.255.255.0
   tagged 1-2,4-5,10-11,Trk2
   exit
vlan 99
   name "DMZ"
   untagged 23
   ip address 10.12.99.254 255.255.255.0
   exit
fault-finder bad-driver sensitivity high
fault-finder bad-transceiver sensitivity high
fault-finder bad-cable sensitivity high
fault-finder too-long-cable sensitivity high
fault-finder over-bandwidth sensitivity high
fault-finder broadcast-storm sensitivity high
fault-finder loss-of-link sensitivity high
fault-finder duplex-mismatch-HDx sensitivity high
fault-finder duplex-mismatch-FDx sensitivity high
timesync sntp
sntp unicast
sntp server priority 1 192.146.137.13 3
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.12.99.1
ip route 10.12.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.12.99.1
ip route 10.12.2.0 255.255.255.0 10.12.99.1
ip route 10.12.3.0 255.255.255.0 10.12.99.1
ip route 100.100.100.0 255.255.255.0 10.12.99.1
snmp-server community "snmp-public" operator
snmp-server community "monitor" operator
spanning-tree
spanning-tree 4 path-cost 41000
spanning-tree Trk1 priority 4
spanning-tree Trk2 priority 4
spanning-tree priority 7
no autorun
password manager
```

And last but not least the routing...

```
                               IP Route Entries

  Destination        Gateway         VLAN Type      Sub-Type   Metric     Dist.
  ------------------ --------------- ---- --------- ---------- ---------- -----
  0.0.0.0/0          10.12.99.1      99   static               1          1
  10.12.1.0/24       Client_PCs      121  connected            1          0
  10.12.2.0/24       Production      122  connected            1          0
  10.12.3.0/24       Servers         123  connected            1          0
  10.12.99.0/24      DMZ             99   connected            1          0
  100.100.100.0/24   DEFAULT_VLAN    1    connected            1          0
  127.0.0.0/8        reject               static               0          0
  127.0.0.1/32       lo0                  connected            1          0
  172.16.230.0/24    ISCSI           20   connected            1          0
```

I can't get VLAN 122 and VLAN 123 to talk to each other, so I assume the route is wrong, but if I try to add a route...

ip route 10.12.2.0/24 10.12.3.254

I get this error.
    10.12.3.254 can not be switch IP address and route gateway at the same time.

I must have something configured wrongly, but I can't work out what it is.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A 2910 with activated `ip routing` routes from and to any VLAN that it has an IP address assigned in.

So, if a node can't reach one VLAN subnet from another it's likely not in the correct VLAN.

`ip route 10.12.2.0/24 10.12.3.254` can't work since 10.12.2.0/24 is already connected locally and 10.12.3.254 is the switch itself - you can't tell it to route back to itself.

Additionally,

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.12.99.1
ip route 10.12.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.12.99.1
ip route 10.12.2.0 255.255.255.0 10.12.99.1
ip route 10.12.3.0 255.255.255.0 10.12.99.1
ip route 100.100.100.0 255.255.255.0 10.12.99.1
```

don't make sense. All these subnets are local and can't be routed elsewhere.

btw: firmware version 14.38 is ancient (before 2011 when we bought 2910s)...

**PS**: You're binding IP addresses to all VLANs, including iSCSI and DMZ - as stated above, the 2910 **will route into and out of all these networks** which is most surely not intended. You'll need to either remove these IP addresses and route/filter between these VLANs elsewhere or configure ACLs that allow the traffic you want while filtering everything else. Note that the 2910 doesn't allow VLAN ACLs, only port ACLs.

Comment: Ah, last time I checked I didn't find updated firmware, though I have just now, I'll give it an upgrade and see what happens.

Comment: HPE downloads are a mess currently. You can find the 2910al-24G downloads in https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/Downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J9145A&lang=en&cc=us&prodSeriesId=3901671 right now.